# Construct a Permuter

Tags: code-golf, permutations, open-ended-function

For this challenge you are going to make a function (your function may be a complete program) that takes a list as input and returns a permutation of that list.  Your function must obey the following requirements.

- It must be deterministic.
- Composing your function with itself a variable number of times should be capable of getting a list to any of its permutations.

This is a code-golf question so answers will be scored in bytes, with less  bytes being better.

### Further rules

- You may take any type of list, (`[Integer]`,`[String]`,`[[Integer]]`) as long as it

  - Can be non empty
  - Can contain distinct objects with at least 16 possible values.  (You can't use a Haskell `[()]` and claim your function is `id`)
  - Can contain duplicate objects (no sets)
- You may write a program or a function, but must obey standard IO.

Comment: But `S_n` is only cyclic for `n<3`

Comment: @LeakyNun, it's not asking for a single permutation which generates the symmetric group: it's asking for a `next_permutation` function.

Comment: Would it suffice to only permute lists of 0's and1's?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point of this restriction. If you allow lists of Booleans, what's the point of not allowing iterables over any two distinct items?

Comment: @Dennis You make a good point.  I will disallowed lists of booleans. Or types that have less than 16 possible values.

Answer (score 4):

### CJam (11 bytes)

```
{_e!_@a#(=}
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%5B2%201%203%202%5D%7B%0A%0A%7B_e!_%40a%23(%3D%7D%0A%0A~_p%7D12*%3B) showing the full cycle for a four-element list with one duplicate element.

#### Dissection

```
{      e# Define a block
  _e!  e#   Find all permutations of the input. Note that if there are duplicate
       e#   elements in the input then only distinct permutations are produced.
       e#   Note also that the permutations are always generated in lexicographic
       e#   order, so the order is independent of the input.
  _@a# e#   Find the index of the input in the list
  (=   e#   Decrement and get the corresponding element of the list
       e#   Incrementing would also have worked, but indexing by -1 feels less
       e#   wrong than indexing by the length, and makes this more portable to
       e#   GolfScript if it ever adds a "permutations" built-in
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>145</s> <s>139</s> <s>137</s> <s>134</s> 108 bytes

*Saved a whopping 25 bytes thanks to @Neil!*

Takes input as an array of alphabetical characters. Returns the next permutation as another array.

```js
a=>(t=x=y=-1,a.map((v,i)=>v<a[i+1]?(t=v,x=i):y=i>x&v>t?i:y),a[x]=a[y],a[y]=t,a.concat(a.splice(x+1).sort()))
```

#### How?

This is a [generation in lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order) that processes the 4 following steps at each iteration:

1. Find the largest index *X* such that *a[X] < a[X+1]*

   ```js
   a.map((v, i) => v < a[i + 1] ? (t = v, x = i) : ...)
   ```
2. Find the largest index *Y* greater than *X* such that *a[Y] > a[X]*

   ```js
   a.map((v, i) => v < a[i + 1] ? ... : y = i > x & v > t ? i : y)
   ```
3. Swap the value of *a[X]* with that of *a[Y]*

   ```js
   a[x] = a[y], a[y] = t
   ```
4. Sort the sequence from *a[X + 1]* up to and including the final element, in ascending lexicographic order

   ```js
   a.concat(a.splice(x + 1).sort())
   ```

Example:

[image: steps]

#### Demo

```js
let f =

a=>(t=x=y=-1,a.map((v,i)=>v<a[i+1]?(t=v,x=i):y=i>x&v>t?i:y),a[x]=a[y],a[y]=t,a.concat(a.splice(x+1).sort()))

for(a = ["A", "B", "C", "D"], n = 0; n < 25; n++) {
  console.log(a.join(','));
  a = f(a);
}
```

Comment: Can't you sort rather than reversing? Also I think `v<a[i+1]&&(t=v,x=i)` saves a byte, and you might be able to make more savings using `splice` instead of two `slice`s.

Comment: @Neil Good catch!

Comment: I think I was able to merge the two `map`s as well, for 112 bytes: `a=>(t=x=y=-1,a.map((v,i)=>v<a[i+1]?(t=v,x=i):y=i>x&v>t?i:y),a[x]=a[y],a[y]=t,t=a.splice(++x).sort(),a.concat(t))`

Comment: I have to admit I didn't think `a.concat(a.splice(++x).sort())` was going to work otherwise I would have tried it...

Comment: @Neil Thanks! Updated. (With 4 more bytes saved because we don't really need *t* to *concat()*).

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica + Combinatorica (Built-in Package) 34 Bytes

19 bytes to load the package and 15 for the function.

```
<<"Combinatorica`";NextPermutation
```

Usage:

```
%@{c, b, a}
```

Without the built-in, 61 Bytes

```
Extract[s=Permutations[Sort@#],Mod[s~Position~#+1,Length@s]]&
```

Combinatorica is supposed to be fully incorporated into Mathematica, but I think the NextPermutation function was overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 90 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
def f(l):p=[*permutations(sorted(l))];return p[-~p.index(l)%len(p)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BCoMwEADvvmIvhUS0tHqz@BKRIrhpA3F3WdfSXvr1NPQ2zBxGPvZk6nMOyhtEQzXmtEPchNXqasUAwSU/yDjVgrodtlhk2t1eOq4l@fmmaIcSyNR@5RxpxXfxp4TkxM85jfhakoskhznvq8AKd4gEutADXXfxQwWQYPyfCopGsoLZ9U3XXP0P)

Answer (score 2):

## C++, 42 bytes

```
#include <algorithm>
std::next_permutation
```

This exact operation is a builtin in C++.

Comment: Why the space after `#include`?

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
Œ¿’œ?Ṣ
```

Cycles through the permutations in descending lexicographical order.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opEP7HzXMPDrZ/uHORf8Ptx@ecGS/wtFJD3fOeNS0JlLh4Y7tjxrmKASlFqQmlqSm5FQqJBYUAMnSvJLMHIWSjFSFotTi0pySYoXEolSFvHyFnPy89NQioHxmYWmqnkJAUWpJSaVuQVFmXone///RhjoKRjoKxkAUCwA)

#### How it works

```
Œ¿’œ?Ṣ  Main link. Argument: A (array)

Œ¿      Compute the permutation index n of A, i.e., the index of A in the
        lexicographically sorted list of permutations of A.
  ’     Decrement the index by 1, yielding n-1.
     Ṣ  Sort A.
   œ?   Getthe (n-1)-th permutation of sorted A.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 154 bytes

```python
x=input()
try:exec'%s=max(k for k in range(%s,len(x))if x[%s-1]<x[k]);'*2%tuple('i1kjii');x[i-1],x[j]=x[j],x[i-1];x[i:]=x[:i-1:-1]
except:x.sort()
print x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BbsMgEETP5iv2YgEViWS3J1L3R5Cl0HjTEDsYAVE3X@9C2l5Ws08zmgmPfFl9vxEM4Hy4ZyFZLDphVez74haEIx3Br7kYIGrWxL2dJlGgZM0zU/yLvX1OVgOxJkTnM5ACvvvgijVIeALO@UbDf0OOD10xb9NwsyRmOK8R5meB9V8o2qQW9IKkdGcg06ZdN76TmUd54C99m@9hQcFdN1@d4/JAxhWDInMdh3rUL6hcV6LLpwtgSCcMWdM@rbEO@du61XmmU9AreFXwNv4A)

Comment: I think this is shorter as a function that permutes the list in-place.

Comment: I tried that, but `exec` gave me all kinds of errors in a function

Answer (score 1):

## C, 161 bytes

Actual O(n) algorithm.

```c
#define S(x,y){t=x;x=y;y=t;}
P(a,n,i,j,t)int*a;{for(i=n;--i&&a[i-1]>a[i];);for(j=n;i&&a[--j]<=a[i-1];);if(i)S(a[i-1],a[j])for(j=0;j++<n-i>>1;)S(a[i+j-1],a[n-j])}
```

Example usage:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i;
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    for (i = 0; i < 25; ++i) {
        printf("%d %d %d %d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
        P(a, 4);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ṢŒ!Q©i⁸‘ị®
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9qZWxsef//4bmixZIhUcKpaeKBuOKAmOG7i8Ku////WzEsMywxXQ)

Sort > all permutation > find input > add 1 > index into "all permutation

Comment: @PeterTaylor I've fixed it.

Comment: There are specific builtins for permutations (i.e. you can just do `Œ¿‘œ?Ṣ`). I didn't feel like stealing since, well, same algo.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer it might be a bit messy for inputs that contain duplicates.

Comment: Hmm...I guess so, I had a version which did work for that previously but you seem to use the `Q` thingy. You can still golf to `ṢŒ!Qµi³‘ị`.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
œêD¹k>è
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6OTDq1wO7cy2O7zi//9oQx0FIDKOBQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 117 bytes

Takes input/output as string list of lower letters

```php
$a=str_split($s=$argn);rsort($a);if(join($a)!=$s)for($n=$s;($c=count_chars)(++$n)!=$c($s););else$n=strrev($s);echo$n;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY6xCsIwFEX3/IXhDQndu7wGB@ngootjIcSYthFJwkt0Ef31mhac7uVyONw0p6XbpzkxRxRJk0uRig@T@Pb6dL4cD71EBoamoLi5WnvjyMZIAsE3Tde2KN8LGJUL6ZwevgjIasMlUq4qAUaiH8U9@rD2nYIsVwGE2lCAVTY@Q9F2NpSlaBoIK2SrSKJE98iuotVP7rVtzs4RAi5r8qGAHwL/X6w7@yw/)